Visual Studio Code taking up 900 GiB?
I'm trying to clean out some storage. When I run df -h, I get this weird output-
(py39) XXXXXXXXXX@air ~ % df -h          
Filesystem                              Size    Used   Avail Capacity iused ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk3s1s1                         926Gi    12Gi    16Gi    44%    404k  173M    0%   /
devfs                                  199Ki   199Ki     0Bi   100%     688     0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk3s6                           926Gi    24Ki    16Gi     1%       0  173M    0%   /System/Volumes/VM
/dev/disk3s2                           926Gi    11Gi    16Gi    41%    1.6k  173M    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot
/dev/disk3s4                           926Gi   632Mi    16Gi     4%     295  173M    0%   /System/Volumes/Update
/dev/disk1s2                           500Mi   6.0Mi   482Mi     2%       1  4.9M    0%   /System/Volumes/xarts
/dev/disk1s1                           500Mi   6.2Mi   482Mi     2%      36  4.9M    0%   /System/Volumes/iSCPreboot
/dev/disk1s3                           500Mi   1.0Mi   482Mi     1%      59  4.9M    0%   /System/Volumes/Hardware
/dev/disk3s5                           926Gi   884Gi    16Gi    99%    5.1M  173M    3%   /System/Volumes/Data
map auto_home                            0Bi     0Bi     0Bi   100%       0     0     -   /System/Volumes/Data/home
/dev/disk3s1                           926Gi    12Gi    16Gi    44%    404k  173M    0%   /System/Volumes/Update/mnt1
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app   926Gi   892Gi   7.8Gi   100%    5.1M   82M    6%   /private/var/folders/8f/br10514d7s5flpfcf8y7j40r0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/81772347-6498-4D22-86B3-D48C3F8CAA23

Am I misreading this- why is VSCode here, and why is it taking up 900 GiB? Would love any support here! Thanks.

Welcome to Ask Different. File systems can be weird. Could you edit in diskutil list to see the storage layout on all drives?
